# Pandas: Forward fill missing value by each group of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data with group level as ['color', 'fruit', 'date', 'value'].

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['Green','Green', 'Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Red'], 
                    'fruit' : ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple'],
                    'date': ['2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-02-01', '2011-02-01'],
                    'value': [ 1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3 , np.nan]})


Output:


Class   fruit   date    value
0   Green   Banana  2011-01-01  1.0
1   Green   Banana  2011-01-02  NaN
2   Green   Apple   2011-01-01  NaN
3   Green   Apple   2011-01-02  2.0
4   Yellow  Banana  2011-02-01  3.0
5   Yellow  Apple   2011-02-01  NaN
```

I need to fill down for 'value' where for a date we have no data. So this fill down would only be limited to ['color', 'fruit'] level.

I am trying to fill down with
`df = df.groupby(['color', 'fruit', 'date'])['value'].mean().replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')`
but this spills the data over to next associated group of [color, fruit]

```
Expected Output:


Class   fruit   date    value
0   Green   Banana  2011-01-01  1.0
1   Green   Banana  2011-01-02  1.0
2   Green   Apple   2011-01-01  NaN
3   Green   Apple   2011-01-02  2.0
4   Yellow  Banana  2011-02-01  3.0
5   Yellow  Apple   2011-02-01  NaN
```

Comment: are you looking for df.groupby(["color", "fruit"])["value"].ffill()?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this solves my question. I was trying with the 'Date' column included in groupby under the impression that if I didn't, I would lose that detail in my output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pandas.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) :

```
m = data.groupby(["color", "fruit"]).cumcount().astype(bool)

data["value"] = data["value"].ffill().where(m, data["value"])
```

Or as mentionned by @*Mustafa Aydin*, simply use [`GroupBy.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) :

```
data["value"] = data.groupby(["color", "fruit"])["value"].ffill()
```

Output :

```
print(data)

   color   fruit        date  value
0  Green  Banana  2011-01-01    1.0
1  Green  Banana  2011-01-02    1.0
2  Green   Apple  2011-01-01    NaN
3  Green   Apple  2011-01-02    2.0
4    Red  Banana  2011-02-01    3.0
5    Red   Apple  2011-02-01    NaN
```